# How would one get the end points of a polyline?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, shapely

I am attempting to write a script to get the end points of a series polylines, and then use those end points to create a polygon.   I'm not sure which tools to begin to use on this project.

I would prefer to use QGIS or even better a python script using open source tools.

Comment: This is a similar post which outlines retrieving the end nodes of a street segment in qGIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28092/is-there-any-way-to-extract-coordinates-of-a-road-segment-using-qgis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html), more "Pythonic",  and list slicing:

```
import fiona
with fiona.drivers():
   for line in fiona.open("some_shapefile.shp"):
         # print first and last point of every line
         print line['geometry']['coordinates'][0], line['geometry']['coordinates'][-1]
```

And with [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html):

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
for line in fiona.open("some_shapefile.shp"):
   print Point(line['geometry']['coordinates'][0]), Point(line['geometry']['coordinates'][-1])
```

And you can construct you polygon and save it with Fiona

New: using the suggestion of sgillies (boundary) with the shape function of shapely

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
for line in fiona.open("some_shapefile.shp"):
     print shape(line['geometry']).boundary[0], shape(line['geometry']).boundary[1]
```

Comment: Gene, the boundary() method of a Shapely object might be more reliable. See http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#MultiLineString.

Comment: Great answer, gene. Just one correction, the boundary of the MultiLineString could have more than 2 points if it is complex.

Comment: @gene great answer, thank you! How can I store these points in another shapefile instead of print using shapely?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this  with the [GDAL/OGR python](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython) bindings. Here's a link to the [OGR API tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html).

A worked example:

```
from osgeo import ogr

ds=ogr.Open(somepolylines)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()
for i in range(lyr.GetFeatureCount()):
    feat=lyr.GetFeature(i)
    geom=feat.GetGeometryRef()
    firstpoint=geom.GetPoint(0)
    lastpoint=geom.GetPoint(geom.GetPointCount()-1)
    print firstpoint[0],firstpoint[1],lastpoint[0],lastpoint[1] #X,Y,X,Y
```