# Generate Point Layer at Line Intersection

Tags: polygon, vector, intersection, qgis-processing

I have a line layer that is actually buffer polygons converted to a line layer. I would like to generate points at all places where 3 or more lines intersect. I would settle for places where 2 or more lines intersect. I know that this is possible to do if all the lines were different layers. What I need is a method to do this when all the lines are contained in a single shapefile. There are too many lines to separate them into individual files.

Comment: Related post if you're open to scripting: [Intersecting lines get crossings](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/137909/64955)

Comment: I'll take a look, though scripting is not my forte.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in three (or four) steps:

(1) Create nodes at intersections

`Processing Toolbox | GRASS | Vector | v.clean` and select `break` option.

(2) Extract nodes as points layer.

`Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geomerty tools | Extract nodes`

(3) Only keep duplicated points (Nodes)

1. Open attribute table of `Nodes` (output of `Extract nodes` tool)
2. Give an expression: `count( "id", group_by:= geom_to_wkt($geometry))` ...assuming you have an `id` field.
3. Remove features whose count is only 1 (one).

(4: optional) Remove duplicates (e.g. Delete duplicate geometries tool...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the line intersections tool from the Vector drop-down menu.  Choose Analysis Tools and then Line Intersections.

[image]

Comment: This is an answer for separate shapefiles, I don't think this tool works for intersections within the same shapefile.

Comment: Yes this won't work for me since the lines are all in the same file.