# Getting end points of polygon using GeoTools?

Tags: polygon, geotools

I am trying to get the end points of a polygon which presents a building in a shp file.

Do you know if there is any function in geotools or the steps that i have to follow to do this?

i find a relative question: [how would one get the end points of a polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86040/how-would-one-get-the-end-points-of-a-polyline)
But it is not what i need.

Comment: what do you mean by the end points of a polygon? they are closed by definition so there is no beginning or end, do you mean max and min in some direction?

Comment: Are you referring to the vertices of the polygon representing a building?

Comment: Yes, i am talking about the vertices of the polygon representing a building..? do you know how i can "identify" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got your Polygons from your shapefile you can get all vertices using JTS [`getCoordinates()`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Polygon.html#getCoordinates()) method:

```
// get first coordinate
Coordinate first = yourPolygon.getCoordinates()[0];
// get last coordinate (same as first)
Coordinate last = yourPolygon.getCoordinates()[yourPolygon.getCoordinates().length-1];
// get last coordinate before closing
Coordinate lastBeforeClosing = yourPolygon.getCoordinates()[yourPolygon.getCoordinates().length-2];
```