# Export Lat long of Line/Polyline in QGIS with start to end

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a polyline layer in QGIS, and I am trying to get the list of lat longs of each of the vertices and their path.

As you can see from the image below, I have tried the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113147/192931). I have extracted the vertices of the lines and I can calculate the lat long of each of these vertices.

But the only thing missing is the **trail/path/direction of the coordinates**. I need to extract, not only the lat longs of the vertices but also the direction (coord A to coord B to C to D etc., or D-C-B-A, order so far is not important yet).

[image]

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the `extract vertices` tool, which extracts all vertices and adds the angle of the line at the vertice, as well as its distance along the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use "Extract Vertices" tool, it gives a clue for the directions. It adds `vertex_index` column.

[image]

Then extract the vertices to CSV and set `GEOMETRY` = `AS_XY`

[image]

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood this vertex_index column. I thought the column was arbitrary/not related to my goal

Answer (score 3):

[`QgsLineString`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsLineString.html) has a [`numPoints` method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsLineString.html#qgis.core.QgsLineString.numPoints) and a [`pointN` method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsLineString.html#qgis.core.QgsLineString.pointN) so combining those in a for loop should do what you want. But it might be easiest to just use the [`points` method](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsLineString.html#qgis.core.QgsLineString.points) to get a list of the points (I can't think of any reason they would not be in order along the line).