# C# lib to extract points from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, c#

I'm looking for a C# library that is able to extract from line shapefile all points of the selected line in a sequential manner from the start to the end of the line.

I know it's doable with [Python and QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28092/is-there-any-way-to-extract-coordinates-of-a-road-segment-using-qgis), but I'm looking for C# lib since it shall be connected to other modules of the system.

Comment: Did you try SharpMap? https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap

Comment: There are a large number of libraries which could accomplish this task; please edit the question to detail the libraries you have identified so far. You could also create a new one in under 300 lines of code.  GIS SE is more about questions with implementing details garnered from primary research than the primary research itself.